# need to stretch a div to height of user's browser window

Tags: html, css

newb here again,
i'm pretty sure i knew this at one point but i no longer remember.

here's my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rachelcat/PHG6U/

obviously this is not the font i am using but let's deal with it.

```
height: 100%
```

^ i tried this and it makes everything dissppear.

i am aware i have the lines set to 800px which is why they stop, but without making them like "4000px" height how would i make it so it always corrects to the browser size? (whatever size that may be) without necessarily having the extra 1000 pixels when you scroll down?

i assume this has an easy answer and i'm just really dumb.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Do you want to stretch the `div` (skew it) or get rid of the scrollbars? If it's the latter, http://jsfiddle.net/PHG6U/10/ will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [parent elements' heights to 100%](http://jsfiddle.net/PHG6U/23/), along with the sideline divs. When using percentages, an element's height is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block.

```
html { 
    background: #FFFDDB;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Pompiere', cursive;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```